# does matlab filter funtion use all the data information

Tags: matlab, precision, numerical-methods, intel-mkl

Please see sample code below for usage of `filter` function in Matlab. For truncated input, I expected to get exact result up to the truncate point, but there are tiny differences, although it is within double precision. Is this expected behavior?

```
X = randn(10000,1);
b = ones(1, 500) / 500;
Y = filter(b,1,X);
Y1 = filter(b,1,X(1:end-1));
tmpdiff = Y(1:end-1)-Y1;
sum(abs(tmpdiff)) % not equal to zero; in the order of 10^(-16)
plot(tmpdiff)  % some spikes
```

Comment: “within double precision”. If you compute something in two different ways, you should expect rounding errors to cause differences. Just changing the order of additions will do this.

Comment: or create a filter object where you specify the word length of the input, output and of the coefficients

Answer (score 1):

One should expect identical results for truncated inputs, the nonzero discrepancies in the question are not ideal and could be avoided. The problem is the MKL code branch used. When checking the MKL version, I got:

```
Intel(R) Math Kernel Library Version 2018.0.3 Product Build 20180406 for Intel(R) 64 architecture applications, CNR branch AVX2
```

By setting an environment variable `MKL_DEBUG_CPU_TYPE=4`, the CNR branch is switched to `AVX`, and the nonzero results are gone.